# Как подключить БД MySql в Python скрипт?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

Я имею базу данных в MySql. Мне нужно, чтобы с ней мог взаимодействовать Python 3 скрипт.

Конкретнее: создавать новые элементы, редактировать элементы, удалять элементы.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Эммм... попробовать почитать [документацию](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html) - не наш метод? примеры там посмотреть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставите зависимости:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Подключение к существующей базе данных:

```
try:
    with connect(
        host="localhost",
        user=input("Имя пользователя: "),
        password=getpass("Пароль: "),
        database="MyBase",
    ) as connection:
        print(connection)
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Ну, а дальше уже стандартные операции взаимодействия с БД найдете в инете

Comment: Теперь выдаёт такую ошибку: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)

Comment: убедитесь, что СУБД запущена или попробуйте 127.0.0.1

Comment: Все запущено на сервере, сам сервер онлайн, а с ip тоже самое выдаёт.

Comment: сервер удаленно или локально расположен?

Comment: Удаленно, 000webhost

Comment: А скрипт запускаете где? у себя на компьютере или скрипт на сервере запускаете?

Comment: Скрипт запускаю на своём Пк

Comment: Тогда в поле "host" должен быть IP-адрес сервера где Ваша БД